# Increase bandwidth usage of Windows 10 remote desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a desktop computer connected to Gigabit LAN. This is the remote desktop host. I also have a laptop, also connected to Gigabit LAN. This is the client. The screen resolution of the laptop is 2560*1440. It connects to a separate account on the desktop, and it works great. The quality is crisp and it's relatively smooth.

However, upon inspecting the network traffic, I noticed the Remote Desktop connection uses at most 50mbps, and about 5mbps on average. This is nowhere near the 1000mbps the connection is capable of.

I understand why this is happening. Remote Desktop is designed for over-the-network connections or multiple LAN clients. Though, in my case I want much higher quality, specifically a stable 60fps.

*Final goal*:
Connect *laptop* to *desktop*, such that the connection is nearly inconceivable due to high performance.

Is it at all possible to utilize more bandwidth with Remote Desktop or is there another software or hardware solution to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you have more bandwidth, doesn't mean, Remote Desktop will suddenly start eating up the bandwidth.

There's lots of compression going on, and there are settings that you can change in the experience tab of the client that will work better on fast connections such as yours.

But that said, it is impossible for Remote Desktop to use more bandwidth if it simply has no additional data to send. Remote Desktop itself simply doesn't offer the experience you are looking for. There are other platforms that might do this, but I wonder how much your problem is due to network bandwidth, and not because of other limitations.

For example, streaming 2560x1440 at 60fps requires a huge amount of data. So your harddrive needs to be fast enough too, not to mention your CPU and GPU.

But that said, even if it were, Remote Desktop itself is not meant to be used for this purpose, so you will definitely need a different tool for this.

Comment: You answer seems quite lackluster. I have mentioned in my question that I understand the original intent of RDP, which you have echoed. I have also asked, whether or not anyone knows a different solution which could help out in this case, which you can again, just echo, and do not evaluate. Finally, I'm aware that 1440p@60 does require a lot of bandwidth, however, it's definitely <1gbps.

Comment: Yes. But please understand that SuperUser is not a place where you can request software suggestions. I explained why it happens because that is the best I can do for it being in the scope of SuperUser. So is it possible with RDP? No. You do need other software for it. That is my answer. But Software Recommendations are off-topic, besides I can't tell you software because I don't have experience with other software.

Comment: You are absolutely right that software recommendations are off-topic, and I apologize for this misunderstanding. Good day to you, Sir.

Comment: I forgive you. :) Good day to you too. :)